# Problem with tsconfig path alias and rollup.js

Tags: typescript, alias, rollup

I am experiencing an issue with aliasing, rollup and typescript. My generated runtime code in the `index.js` can process the aliasing without any problems. The type tree generated by `@rollup/plugin-typescript` takes the references inside my react component and copies it 1-to-1 into my `dist/index.d.ts`, including the `@/my-dependency` alias. This leads to types not being able to resolve in the resulting dist.

My generated files look like so:

```
dist
├── dts
│   ├── components
│   └── index.d.ts
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── index.js.map
├── public
│   └── external
└── types
```

I have a tsconfig with these parameters :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "dts",
        "paths": { "@/my-dependency": ["./src/types/some-folder/app/index"] }
    },
}
```

I have a rollup config like so :

```
export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
                exports: 'named',
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            alias({
                entries: [{ find: '@/my-dependency', replacement: './src/types/some-folder/app/index' }],
            }),
            external(),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
                exclude: ['**/testData/**/*', '**/*.chunk.js'],
            }),
            terser(),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: 'dist/dts/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```

I considered using [rollup-plugin-typescript-paths](https://github.com/simonhaenisch/rollup-plugin-typescript-paths), but it does not work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find workaround for this problem with other package. I have used tsc-alias with separeted configuration to tell which alias path should be rewritten and where to find 'em.

Example "rollup.config.mjs"

```js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    external: ['react-dom'],
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
        exclude: [
          'node_modules',
          // Exclude test files
          /\.test.((js|jsx|ts|tsx))$/,
          // Exclude story files
          /\.stories.((js|jsx|ts|tsx|mdx))$/,
        ],
      }),
    ],
  },
];
```

example "tsconfig.json"

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "jsx": "react" /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */,
    "module": "ESNext" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "baseUrl": "." /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,
    "paths": { "@src/*": ["src/*"] } /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */,
    "typeRoots": [
      // default types root
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ] /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */,
    "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */,
    "sourceMap": true /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */,
    "outDir": "dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "declarationDir": "types" /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

"tscaliasconfig.json" file look something like this

```js
      {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist/esm/types",
        "declarationDir": "dist/esm/types",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { "@src/*": ["src/*"] }
      }
 }
```

packageJson script

```
"build": "rollup -c && tsc-alias -p tscaliasconfig.json && dts-bundle-generator -o dist/index.d.ts dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
```

Optional* You can see that I have used "dts-bundle-generator" instead of "rollup-plugin-dts" but the output is practically the same. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `alias` (I suppose you import it from `@rollup/plugin-alias` package, question doesn't mention this) is use in a wrong place. The config is split in two parts and `alias` used only in the first one, but expected results (bundled d.ts) is coming from the second one where `dts` is used (I suppose we are speaking about `rollup-plugin-dts` package).

In order to solve this `alias` should be in the second block of the config array, like:

```
export default [...,
{
    input: 'dist/dts/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
    // external: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/], // You can skip some css imports if you output css modules unchanged
    plugins: [
        alias({
            entries: [{
                find: '@/my-dependency',
                replacement: path.resolve('./dist/dts/types/some-folder/app/index'),
            },
            // Optional in the case of question, but another popular alias:
            {
                find: '@',
                // In tsconfig this would be like `"paths": { "@/*": ["./src/*"] }`
                replacement: path.resolve('./dist/dts'), 
            }],
        })
        dts(),
    ],
},
]
```

In the example above `replacement` is set to resolved path to **the output folder** of `@rollup/plugin-typescript` plugin. It should not be set to the source (`src`) folder as `dts()` plugin cares only about given entry point, so alias has to be resolved to the folder where all output `.d.ts` files placed after build of the first config with `@rollup/plugin-typescript`, not the source folder.

UPDATE:

Maybe it is better to consider to use `src/index.ts` as the entry point for the second (DTS) block and skip declaration emits in the first completely using tsconfig options or `typescript()` plugin overrides. In this case output will have only single bundled `.d.ts` file.